# Email not sending ASP.NET MVC 4 Using SMTPClient

Tags: c#, email, asp.net-mvc-4, smtp, smtpclient

i would like to add some more functionalities to my method, such as an email to be sent once the user has successfully edited the data. i debugged the code but no errors are generated so i do not know where i am going wrong.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(EditPTG eptg)
    {
        try
        {
            using (ManageGrade gradeLogic = new ManageGrade(ref uow))
            {
                foreach (var ptg in eptg.ptgForGrade)
                {
                    ptg.Overwritten = true;
                    ptg.Active = true;
                    productToGradeLogic.Update(ptg);
                }

                //Need to investigate why we need to recalculate grade at this point of time - Sri to Mark??
                //eptg.grade = GradeHelpers.RecalculateGradeStringFromProductAssignment(eptg.ptgForGrade, eptg.grade);
                SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("www.Hotmail.com", 25);
                // smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
                smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

                mail.From = new MailAddress("www.example.com");
                mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("hi@hotmail.com"));
                mail.CC.Add(new MailAddress("hello@hotmail.com"));

                smtpClient.Send(mail);
                gradeLogic.Update(eptg.grade);




                TempData["Success"] = "Edit Successful";



                return RedirectToAction("Index");

            }

        }
        catch
        {
            TempData["Failure"] = "Edit Failed, Please Review Your Selections and Try Again.";
            return View(eptg);
        }




    }
```

Comment: You may try the address for SmtpClient as 'smtp.live.com', I don't think that www.hotmail.com is the correct value

Comment: @KimHoang i have tried too but do not seem to do anything

Comment: Try port 587 instead of 25

Comment: @KimHoang still doing the same

Comment: if so I really have no idea, could be a delay in SMTP server or something. Your code is ok.